# Jenkins - Executing a script before any build job built

Tags: build, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I'd like to execute a script before I execute any project/build on a Jenkins server. I've checked out the BuildWrapper script and a couple of others.

These all seem to be based on a specific job, but I'd like to get this sorted to work across any job/build on this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an upstream job that all jobs depends on.

Specifically, In the buildsteps of your job, you can choose "Trigger/Call builds on 
other projects", add ParentJob and select "Block until the triggered 
projects finish their builds" before invoking the buildsteps of your job.

Comment: Uses case where this solution will not help: I'd like to run a script before each job to sanitize the Jenkins slave (eg: kill stray procs, clean tmp, etc).  Using a parent job will not work since it can run on any slave.   

The closest solution I've found was to do the steps in post instead: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Post+Script+Plugin